# Floating elements the first one overlaps the second

Tags: html, css, css-float

I trying to do a simple page that takes the entire browser window. It contains inly two elements, the problem is that the second one is overlapped from the first

```
form 
{
    background-color:#996600;
    width:30%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;    
    font:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    color:#FFF
}

#risultati 
{
    width:70%;
    background-color:#0099FF;
    font:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    color:#FFF
}


<body>

<form action"">
 <label>Inserisci ragione sociale</label>
   <input name="chiave" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)"/>

 <!-- <input type="submit"/> -->
</form>

<p id="risultati">Risultati: <span id="txtHint"></span></p> 


</body>
```

Where is the problem?

EDIT: I noted that the overlap effect only the backgorund property of the second element (the "Risultati" word is normally floated).
I expect that the background occupy the rest of the space of the browser starting from the ending of the first element. Instead it begins from the left side of the browser where the first element is positioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One element is `float: left` while the other is not; this is causing the overlap. Try adding `float: left` to the `#risultati` declaration in your CSS:

```
#risultati 
{
    width:70%;
    background-color:#0099FF;
    font:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    color:#FFF;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: omg it worked.. I swear that already tryed this solution before post the anwer but didn't work. Thanks for helped me, and sorry for the noobish question :(

Comment: Anyway it's not perfect. The second element doesn't allined with the first one, but its positionated one row under